# Merge a temp rank query into single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to merge the following queries into one, however whatever I have tried doesn't seem to work right. The idea of it is to insert the sorted list into a temp table that has an auto incremented field and then take the new list and then update the original table with the updated values.

```
INSERT INTO `TempRank` (`id`, `power`) 
SELECT `Rankable`.`id`, `Rankable`.`SA` AS `power` 
FROM `Rankable` 
INNER JOIN `Accounts` ON `Accounts`.`id` = `Rankable`.`id`
WHERE `Accounts`.`active` = '1' 
ORDER BY `power` DESC;

UPDATE `Rankable`, `TempRank`
SET `Rankable`.`id` = `TempRank`.`id`, 
    `Rankable`.`Rank` = `TempRank`.`Rank`
WHERE `Rankable`.`id` = `TempRank`.`id`
```

Any info is greatly appreciated, I will continue to work on this while I wait for your answers and will update you on what I find. Thank you for help!

Comment: `UPDATE \`Rankable\`, \`TempRank\`` should instead be using an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Yeah, this was written years ago when I basically knew nothing about it and I am finally going back to change it all and make it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE rankable r INNER JOIN temprank t ON r.id=t.id SET r.rank=t.rank
```

Comment: Update rankable AS r INNER JOIN temprank AS t will also work if you prefer to us the AS keyword for aliasing

Comment: You can also add a WHERE clause after the SET if you prefer.